# OpenLayers: How to assign custom id's to clusters to retrieve on click

Tags: javascript, openlayers

we are using OpenLayers 4.6.4 with the ol-ext extension in order to show beautiful looking clusters. That is working fine so far, but we need to link each cluster with custom informations (like putting a simple field into the cluster object) and once the cluster is clicked on the map, i want to retrieve it with the arguments delivered in the callback.

I was not able to find a simple example on putting custom fields on a cluster and retrieving them once i click them on the map.

The event i add my listener is handled by ol.interaction.SelectCluster from ol-ext

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change the cluster features so easily, but that's actually not necessary to get information about it.

Cluster is just a layer source which clusters (who would have guessed) an underlaying source. It creates Features, which in turn have the represented Features stored in a property `features`.

The [ol-ext example](http://view-source:http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/animation/map.animatedcluster.html) demonstrates how to read the contained features:

```
var selectCluster = new ol.interaction.SelectCluster(.....);
selectCluster.getFeatures().on(['add'], function (e)
{   var c = e.element.get('features');
    if (c.length==1)
    {   var feature = c[0];
        $(".infos").html("One feature selected...<br/>(id="+feature.get('id')+")");
    }
    else
    {   $(".infos").text("Cluster ("+c.length+" features)");
    }
})
```

Without any interaction, you could do this:

```
map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
  const feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(
    evt.pixel,
    function(someFeature){ return someFeature; }, // stop at the very first feature
  );
  const containedFeatures = feature.get('features');
});
```

Comment: As dude says clusters are not intended to be used such a way. You can use feature.set(property,value) on cluster features but remember they are recalculated on each zoom/insertion, thus properties will be lost.